# SHA256.DB30.com listing of email account

Tags: web-scanners, sha256, gmail

After searching a gmail account in Google I've found a result for the website SHA256.DB30.com. The page just shows the name of the gmail account and a list with major and minor hash.

From my basic understanding of SHA256 I guess it's nothing to worry about in terms of having the gmail account hacked, but I was wondering if anyone knows whether this is just a standard internet register or if it could be caused by malware or any other exploit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found my email address listed on db30. After a bit more research I found out that my address and password had been harvested during a Gmail security breach in September. Try checking your address at haveibeenpwned.com to checked if yours is listed in any of the major security breach lists.
Also it could be a good idea to change your passwords for your email and any other sites that you use eg.online banking, shopping etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was a bit reluctant to enter my email on that site but after a google search it seems fine. I'd recommend it even if you have no reason to assume your gmail account has been hacked. For me it was either from the gmail security breach or an older Adobe breach from October 2013.